# Matlab simulation through FIS and Markov Process

Tags: markov-process, matlab, simulation

I need to simulate for an academical project how the traffic fluxes (input/output with respect to a monitored area, measured in number of cars) of a city area evolves in correspondence of an event (i.e. the opening of a restricted traffic area to decongest the traffic).
I have some simulated sensors that provide the data: I was thinking to use a combination of a fuzzy system (to assign a membership function to each type of data, e.g. PM10 value and CO2 value) and a markov process: I would need to modify the probability to decrement the number of car in the monitored area (simulating that a car is going out the congested area, towards the new opened area) basing on decisions made by means of a fuzzy system.
So my questions are:

- It is a good way to interpret the problem or there are better ideas that I have not taken into account yet?
- How to implement such a combination of markov chain and fuzzy systems in matlab?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I don't really get why would you mix Fuzziness and Probabilities. HMMs already can give you probabilities without the need of adding Fuzzy systems into the mix.

I would just do a random walk with probabilities of transitions defined by the state of the lights.